# How do I multiply all the elements inside a list by each other?

Tags: python, list, math, operator-keyword, multiplication

Im trying to multiply all the numbers in a list by each other

```
a = [2,3,4]
for number in a:
        total = 1 
        total *= number 
return total
```

The output from this should be 24 but for some reason I get 4. Why is this the case?

Comment: "total" is set to 1 in each loop iteration. You don't want that.

Comment: As of Py3.8: `import math`, `product = math.prod([2, 3, 4])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're initializing total to 1 every iteration of the loop.

The code should be (if you actually *want* to do it manually):

```
a = [2, 3, 4]
total = 1
for i in a:
    total *= i
```

That solves your *immediate* problem but, if you're using Python 3.8 or higher, this functionality is in the `math` library:

```
import math
a = [2, 3, 4]
total = math.prod(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:
Using the prod function from numpy package.

```
import numpy
     ...: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
     ...: b = numpy.prod(a)

In [128]: b
Out[128]: 720
```

Approach 2:
in Python 3.8 , prod is added in the math module:

> math.prod(iterable, *, start = 1)

```
math.prod(a)
```

would do the same

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use numpy then use reduce function.

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Or `reduce(operator.mul, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's `4` is because in the `for` loop, you execute `total = 1`, then you multiple `total` with the current number in each iteration. So it will loop till the end, the last element is `4`, and you multiple 4 to 1, so the total is 4 now.

If you want to multiple all elements in a list. I suggest you use `numpy.prod`:

```
import numpy as np
list = [2,3,4,5]
final = np.prod(list)
```